# How to clear memory when user Log off the app

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that user has to Log in and connect to a Server. And i have maps, pins, a lot of bitmaps and variables, however, I want variables and other unnecessary to be cleared on user Log off

What i want is like a restart the app, like when the user open the app for first time.

I heared about:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess()
```

but not sure when it actually does and how i can call it...

Comment: Where are your variables at? Show us some code!

Comment: You should generally never use killProcess(). Android handles memory management itself, and removes things from memory when it needs the space, why do you need to clear the memory manually?

Comment: Yeah, you should avoid using killProcess. Generally, you should declare some dispose() method in your code that deallocate stuff (like calling dispose(), destroy() etc and declare this variables as null, so they can be GC'ted.

Comment: Well it is working fine at this moment, but what i want is to improve the app avoiding consume too much memory when logging off, what i have is a Map that displays a lot of markers and infowindows with images and stuff

Comment: `finish()` should be all you need for login and logout purposes.

Comment: You can do what Leonardo said, but as Andrew pointed out, once you call finish() on an activity, the memory it was using is up for grabs. Android will remove the objects from memory (even if you don't want it to) as it sees necessary. The Android OS regulates memory usage itself, you shouldn't mess with it.